# XPath using Predicate starts-with but looking for sister value

Tags: xml, xpath

I have seem lots of examples of XPath predicate starts-with that show that as the final filter, but nothing that uses the starts-with predicate to filter and then return a sister value.

For instance, here is sample XML:

```
<myXML>
  <InputAssumptions>
    <Data>
      <General>
        <GeneralTable>
          <GeneralMethod>PGR</GeneralMethod>
          <vData>
            <vEntry>
              <EffectiveDate RelativeTo="Absolute">2015-06-01</EffectiveDate>
              <Percentage>0.01</Percentage>
            </vEntry>
            <vEntry>
              <EffectiveDate RelativeTo="Absolute">2016-06-01</EffectiveDate>
              <Percentage>0.02</Percentage>
            </vEntry>
            <vEntry>
              <EffectiveDate RelativeTo="Absolute">2017-06-01</EffectiveDate>
              <Percentage>0.03</Percentage>
            </vEntry>
            <vEntry>
              <EffectiveDate RelativeTo="Absolute">2018-06-01</EffectiveDate>
              <Percentage>0.04</Percentage>
            </vEntry>
            <vEntry>
              <EffectiveDate RelativeTo="Absolute">2019-06-01</EffectiveDate>
              <Percentage>0.05</Percentage>
            </vEntry>
          </vData>
        </GeneralTable>
      </General>
    </Data>
  </InputAssumptions>
</myXML>
```

What I want is to be able to supply a YEAR and return the Percentage for that year.  The data is produced in such a way that there will only ever be one entry for each year.  So simply returning the first entry is fine.

So, I can return the first DATE which starts with "2016" (for example) using the following XPath:

```
/myXML/InputAssumptions/Data/General/GeneralTable/vData/vEntry/EffectiveDate[starts-with(.,"2016")]
```

this returns:

```
<EffectiveDate RelativeTo="Absolute">2016-06-01</EffectiveDate>
```

And... I can return the the first PERCENTAGE which exactly matches "2016-06-01" using the following XPath:

```
/myXML/InputAssumptions/Data/General/GeneralTable/vData/vEntry[EffectiveDate="2016-06-01"]/Percentage
```

this returns:

```
<Percentage>0.02</Percentage>
```

However, I CANNOT seem to figure out how to combine the two and show the corresponding PERCENTAGE using the starts-with predicate function applied to the sister entry of EffectiveDate.

I imagine this is possible, it seems very simple, but I can't find it mentioned anywhere, or at least can't figure out how to search for it...

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

You're so close! Just replace the equality test with a starts-with test:

```
/myXML/InputAssumptions/Data/General/GeneralTable/
vData/vEntry[starts-with(EffectiveDate,"2016-06-01")]/Percentage
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
//vEntry[EffectiveDate[starts-with(.,  '2016')]]/Percentage
```

It selects `<Percentage>` elements that are children of `<vEntry>` elements  that also contain at least one `<EffectiveDate>` element child that starts with `2016`.